# can't send attachment with cakeemail

Tags: cakephp

I can't send an attachment with the email. I don't get an error and I do send the message so the email works but no attachment.

Is my filepath not correct  as the file exists in this file? Is it because I am using windows with file paths?

This is just a test email below to see if this function actually works for an attachment but it isn't working for me. I checked other answers and this seems to be the way to construct this.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html

```
   public function sendEmailattach($to,$message,$subject,$attach) {



                        $Email = new CakeEmail();
                             $Email->config('gmail3'); 
                            $Email->filePaths  = array('D:\crm5\app\Attachments');

                     $Email->attachments =array('Ch9-anna tax.docx');
                             $to='jXXXXX@gmail.com';//testing real email account
                           //  $Email->from( array('admin@a.com.au' => 'A'));
                                 $Email->from( array('jxxxxx@gmail.com' => 'test'));



                             $Email->to($to);
                             $Email->subject($subject);
                             $Email->send();
                              // $Email->send($message);



  }//public


UPDATE
Tried all 3 methods and no error and no attachment?
 //  $Email->attachments('D:\AA-website design\crm5\app\Attachments\Ch9-anna tax.docx') ;

                    $Email->attachments(array('Ch9-anna tax.docx' => array(
                            'file' => 'D:\AA-website design\crm5\app\Attachments\Ch9-anna tax.docx',
                               )   ));     

                  //   $Email->attachments(array('D:\AA-website design\crm5\app\Attachments\Ch9-anna tax.docx'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$email = new CakeEmail('default');

$attachment = [
'file.pdf' => [
    'file' => '/my/absolute/path/on/server/file.pdf',
    'mimetype' => 'application/pdf',
    'contentId' => uniqid()
    ]
];

$variables = ['emailHeader' => 'Hello'];

$email->attachments($attachment);

$email->from(['info@example.com' => 'Example'])
    ->to('recipient@example.com')
    ->subject('Subject')
    ->template('template')
    ->emailFormat('both')
    ->viewVars($variables)
    ->send();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just read the manual instead just looking at the links, honestly I have doubt's you read it at all:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-attachments

It clearly shows that attachments is a method and not a property. It even has examples of what the method accepts.

Comment: This doesnt work! many people have questions about this. I tried all 3 methods and no attachment please see question update. So what now?